Apex pretius nested reports plugin is not able to install
I downloaded the Apex pretius plug for nested reports in Apex 22.1, but it throws this error when I try to install the zip.
**Unable to find file.install.sql**

https://github.com/Pretius/apex-nested-reports/blob/master/README.md
Is this a known issue?
